# How to initialize smoke

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I want to use the [Smoke package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/smoke) and it worked (without using a transformer just in debug mode) on the server side.

On the client side Smoke is already used by Polymer and when I use a method like `assert(sk.isSubclassOf(type, Message));` it fails because internal it checks against the `_parents` collection and this contains only Polymer elements used on my page but none of my other (pure Dart) classes.

How do I initialize Smoke so it recognizes my other classes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using a custom `main()` for my Polymer entry page.

```dart
import 'package:smoke/mirrors.dart' as skm;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

void main() {
  skm.useMirrors(); // worked on the server side without calling this method

  initPolymer().run(() {});
}
```